# Unable to run tests with built-in Testing API in VSCode

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code

New user questions about the **Testing API** in **VSCODE**:
Is there documetation on using the Testing API?  The official documentation looks like it is written for those writing extensions rather than those using the extension.

1. Does an **extension** need to be added to use Testing API?  If so, what is the extension name
2. Does it require changes to the **settings.json** file before it will find the tests?
3. What needs to be **configured** (Extensions added? Project file updated... etc.) to use XUnit tests

Currently a tests folder is at the root of the project.  It contains another folder called tests

Content of the  **tests/tests/GlobalUsings.cs**

`global using Xunit;`

Content of the **tests/tests/LoadTests.cs**

```
namespace MyProjectName.SubprojectName.Tests;

public class LoadTests
{
    private readonly string[] strings = File.ReadAllLines("data/records.txt");

    [Fact]
    public void Load()
    {
        var data = Dataloader.Load(strings);

        Assert.NotEmpty(data.RecordsOfInterst);
    }
}
```